# Write $\frac {x^{t} - 1}{\ln(x)}$ as a power series in $t$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Write $\frac {x^{t} - 1}{\ln(x)}$ as a power series in $t$

First, I managed to show that $$\int_{0}^{1} (\ln x)^k dx = (-1)^{k}k!$$

I also find that $$x^{t} = e^{t\cdot \ln(x)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\cdot t^{k}$$

Now I need to represent $$\frac {x^{t} - 1}{\ln(x)}$$ as a power series of $t$

I am not sure how to proceed from here

**Edit**:
Below is how I derived the power series for $x^t$, it's likely I messed it up.

since $e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot$

Substitute $x = t\ln x$, I get $$e^{t\ln x} = 1 + t\ln x + \frac{(t\ln x)^{2}}{2!} + \frac{(t\ln x)^{3}}{3!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot$$

Here I substituted $\int_{0}^{1} (\ln x)^k dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}k!$ in order to get rid of $(\ln x)^{k}$ and got
$$x^{t} = e^{t\cdot \ln(x)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\cdot t^{k}$$

But I probably shouldn't do that. and instead, I should have
$$e^{t\ln x} = \frac{t^{k}(\ln (x))^{k}}{k!}$$

Comment: @GEdgar My bad, it wasn't supposed to be a series, just a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from $x^t=e^{t\ln x}$, then expand. The $t^k$ coefficient is $\frac{\ln^{k-1}(x)}{k!}$ for $k\ge1$.

Comment: Can you provide some details? If I substitute $x^{t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}t^{k}$ into $\frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln (x)}$ how does $t^{k}$ coefficient becomes $\frac{\ln^{k-1} (x)}{(k-1)!}$ ?

Comment: @SirouEwei Your putative formula for $x^t$ is wrong; its RHS is $1/(1+t)$ when it converges, i.e. for $|t|<1$. You should have $x^t-1=e^{t\ln x}-1=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{t^k\ln^kx}{k!}$.

Comment: After expanding $\frac{ \frac{ t^{k}\ln^{k} x } { k! }  - 1}{\ln x}$, I have $\frac{t^{k}\ln^{k-1}x}{k!} - \frac{1}{\ln x}$. How do I represent $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ as a power series though? @J.G.

Comment: I see that the first term of $\frac{ t^{k}\ln^{k} x } { k! }$ equals $1$ so $-1$ means it starts at $k \geq 1$, I see what you mean now. @J.G.